# Recolor artwork (Illustrator): Colors don't match up

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, color-match

I'm currently working in Illustrator (CMYK, Fogra39) and the colors on my artwork are nice and deep, but when I want to recolor them via "recolor artwork", the colors displayed are a lot duller which makes it hard to tweak the colors when the ones shown are not the ones in the actual artwork.

I added a screenshot. on the top you can see what the colors should look like vs what they look like in the panel.

[image: screenshot of recolor artwork, showing the color discrepancy]

Any idea why this is happening? I'm only experiencing this while working in this specific color profile, my peers don't have the same issue when working with this file (we're on Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to fix the issue, so I hope this will help others with similar issues.

Turns out that illustrator wasn't depicting black as it's supposed to be. We changed the settings here: Illustrator > Preferences > Appearance of black and switch to "Display all blacks accurately"

And in my color settings (Edit > Color settings) I had to turn on "Use black point compensation".

Now everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: It's always been a mystery to me why Adobe sets the default to display colors *inaccurately*. That seems so, so, counterintuitive. Glad you sorted it!

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad we managed to figure it out. No-one else was experiencing these issues in the company, so it was hard to troubleshoot.